# How to fix this "out of memory error " in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, out-of-memory

Two of the lines in my code, commented below, throw "out of memory error". Can this be corrected?

```
[x1,x2]=textread(tline,'%u,%u'); x1 and x2 contains integer value  
 %  disp(x1);
 %     disp(x2);   
previousMovie =  nextMovie;
nextMovie     =  x1;
allMovies     =  [allMovies x1];  /////////      error in this line
if(iline ==1)        
    if((nextMovie ~= previousMovie) & (previousMovie==0))
        currentGenres = x2;     
    end
end   
if(nextMovie == previousMovie)
    currentGenres = [currentGenres x2];/////////       also in this line error
end
```

Comment: plz help me... i am trying alot but nothing is helpful. out of memory error comes in line  allMovies = [allMovies x1];

Comment: Uh... yeah... how **large** is this text file you're reading in?  You think it may have something to do with that?  What does "out of memory error" mean?  Do you know what it means?

Comment: How large is your data? what is the size of allMovies?